# Nested for loops

Tags: apex, loop

I would like to associate all the contacts with name test in them to an account.

```apex
trigger trg1 on Account(after insert){
    List<Contact> conList = [Select Id,LastName from Contact where LastName Like ‘Test%’];
    List<Contact> cList = new List<Contact>();
    for(Account acc: trigger.new){
        for(Contact con: conList){
            con.AccountId = acc.Id;
            cList.add(con);
        }
    }
    update cList;
}
```

How should I avoid nested for loops in the above code using Maps?

Comment: If you want to associate all incoming contacts, with Name `Test` in it, to an account, then why to write trigger on Account, why not write on Contact. Also which account that would be, is there only one account in System already created for all your test contacts?

Comment: @Nagendra Singh There are few test contacts already and I would like to associate them to an account I will be inserting. There are no more incoming test contacts.

Comment: If there are no more incoming contacts just write an anonymous apex. Query all Contacts and just update account Id to it. `Hardcode the account id`, as its just an anonymous apex.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an anonymous apex like this:

```
String accountId = 'Hardcoded Account Id For which you want to associate Contacts to';
List<Contact> conList = [SELECT Id,LastName FROM Contact WHERE LastName LIKE 'Test%' AND AccountId != :accountId LIMIT 10000];
for(Contact con: conList){
    con.AccountId = accountId;

}
Database.update(conList, false);
```

Query all Contacts where your LastName matches, and check if its **not** already associated with that Account, then query that and associate the account id and then update the contacts.

Why limit `10000`, is because, lets say you have more than 10000 contacts which needs to be associated, so as per governor limits, you can only update 10000 records in a single transactions.

You may have to run this multiple times depending on the contacts size.